# Find number of levels reporting structure in java

Tags: java, list, hashmap, hierarchy

I want to calculate the number of levels between manager and employee.

That is, if i give an empid, i would like to know how many managers are there in the hierarchy.
[Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-employees-under-every-manager/) is a sample where we can find the number of direct reports

But i want to find the emp-mgr hierarchy level.

eg. emp , mgr

```
{ "A", "C" },
{ "B", "C" },
{ "C", "D" },
{ "D", "E" },
{ "E", "F" },
{ "F", "F" }
```

In this example C is manager of A, 
C is also manager of B, F is manager 
of C and so on.

```
F -> A = 3(mgrs between)
```

can you please help me in solving this using java

Comment: Seems like an easy task. Have you tried anything? X = A -> Get the manager of X untill X = F. Take the numbers of the previous step.

Comment: I don´t understand your example, please help me. Is it A->C->D->E->F ?

Comment: If we say Manager F and Employee A you want to say level is 4 levels including F else 3?

Comment: I’ve downvoted because of the lack of effort on your side, Jee.

Comment: The problem is unclear to me. Do you start (1) from an employee and a manager (A and F) and want to find their distance in the hierarchy? Or (2) from just an employee and want the distance to the self-managed manager? Or (3) from just the hierarchy wanting to find the greatest distance between any employee and manager?

Comment: actually here i have multiple emp reporting to same mgr like A->B,C,E,
B->D,F,G etc.. so i want to calculate top to bottom or bottom to top levels.

Comment: So in the example the answer is 3 because A -> C -> D -> E -> F, there are 3 managers between A and F, exclusive, and there is no longer path in the management hierarchy than the one quoted — have I got it right?

Answer (score 0):

I ought not give you this as long as you have shown no effort beyond answering one clarifying question. My idea is I start from all managers (C, D, E and F) and count how high I can climb up the management tree from them.

```
public static <T> int treeHeight(Map<T, T> management) {
    // find first level managers
    Collection<T> managers = management.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> ! entry.getKey().equals(entry.getValue()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    int level = 0;
    while (! managers.isEmpty()) {
        level++;
        // find next level managers
        managers = managers.stream()
                .filter(emp -> ! emp.equals(management.get(emp)))
                .map(emp -> management.get(emp))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    }
    return level;
}
```

This method finds the number of steps from the lowest employee (leaf in the management tree) to the self-managing manager (root), that is, 4 in the example (for an empty map or a map consisting solely of the self-managing manager it will return 0). Subtract one to get only the number of managers in between:

```
    Map<String, String> management = new HashMap<>();
    management.put("A", "C");
    management.put("B", "C");
    management.put("C", "D");
    management.put("D", "E");
    management.put("E", "F");
    management.put("F", "F");
    System.out.println(treeHeight(management) - 1);
```

This prints 3.

Comment: Jee, was this helpful? Unless you’re waiting for other answers to come in, feel free to mark as accepted (press the tick mark to the left of the answer) if you think.

Comment: Thank Ole for the reply. This helped me to look more options.
I also need to check more levels like, if the manager has more employees reporting as i mentioned in my previous comments.